# Input validation error on negative numbers in IE11

Tags: html, validation, internet-explorer

When running a webpage With latitude/longitude in Production environment I encountered an unexpected error.

My input field is set to accept values in the range -180 - 180.
However in IE11 values below -153.2 is invalid.
For a field with a range of -90 - 90, values below -65.9 is invalid.
This does only apply to decimal numbers, so -156.6 could be invalid and -157 could be valid.

Is there some kind of logic behind this that I don't see?

For test I'm running this code on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">

  Quantity (between -180 and 180):
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="-180" max="180" step="0.0001"><br>

  <input type="submit">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can reproduce the issue, although this does not seem limited to a specific number range - for example `-176.4` gives me a validation error, whereas `-176.5` works fine ... My guess, a floating point issue maybe? With a step value of `0.0001` I could imagine that leads to rounding errors internally, when you keep in mind the inherent imprecision of floating-point numbers ...

Comment: Yes, that may be a reason. I find it strange, however, that it seems to work for all positive numbers.